# BeautifulSoup... inconsistence fields (May or May not exist)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

`field_b` may or may not exist. `print(field_b.text)` resulted in

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Code:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')

for item in soup.find_all('li', class_='items'):
    field_a=item.find('span', class_='aaa')
    field_b=item.find('span', class_='bbb')
    field_c=item.find('span', class_='ccc')

    print(field_a.text,field_b.text,field_c.text)



result
------
<li class="items><span class="aaa">XXX</span><span class="bbb">XXX</span><span class="ccc">XXX</span></li>
<li class="items><span class="aaa">XXX</span><span class="ccc">XXX</span></li>
<li class="items><span class="aaa">XXX</span><span class="ccc">XXX</span></li>
<li class="items><span class="aaa">XXX</span><span class="bbb">XXX</span><span class="ccc">XXX</span></li>
```

Comment: How about `if field_b:`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your pointer... got it !!!